# Track who uploaded file

Tags: file-upload, ftp

I want to keep track who uploaded the file on server. In my case 50 Developers using 1 server. They are using filezilla to upload file on server. Sometimes we are not able to track who uploaded the particular file last time.

Is there any software other than svn for this tracking ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just make a user for each of them and include them all in one user-group. No need additional software because filezilla will make an activity log and put a username that did the action.

Comment: Will it display the activity properly ? I mean I want to show that log to everyone so that everyone can uderstand easily.

Comment: Well..part of the content of the log are like this :

000002) 2/11/2014 16:15:45 PM - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> USER dev A
(000002) 2/11/2014 16:15:45 PM - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> 331 Password required for dev a
(000002) 2/11/2014 16:15:45 PM - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> PASS ****
(000002) 2/11/2014 16:15:45 PM - dev a (127.0.0.1)> 230 Logged on
(000002) 2/11/2014 16:15:45 PM - dev a (127.0.0.1)> CWD /
(000002) 2/11/2014 16:15:45 PM - dev a (127.0.0.1)> 250 CWD successful. "/" is current directory.

it's text based, but it display all the things like time, user and the action taken.

Comment: (000005) 2/11/2014 16:19:44 PM - dev a (127.0.0.1)> DELE kp realty QA.txt
(000005) 2/11/2014 16:19:44 PM - dev a (127.0.0.1)> 250 File deleted successfully. >>  

that's another example of the log when user "dev A" delete a file called "kp realty QA.txt".